# post pagination in page isn't working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

```
function paginate_posts() {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
    $current = str_pad($current, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $total = str_pad($wp_query->max_num_pages, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $pagination_args = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => 0,
        'mid_size' => 0,
        'next_text' => _("&raquo;"),
        'prev_text' => _("&laquo;"),
    );
    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
        $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(remove_query_arg('s', get_pagenum_link(1))) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

    if (!empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']))
        $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s' => get_query_var('s'));
    $prev = get_previous_posts_link('');
    $next = get_next_posts_link('');
    $links = "<div class='pagination_box'><span class='prev page-num'>$prev</span> <span>Page $current/$total</span> <span class='next page-num'>$next</span></div>";
    echo $links;
}
```

Pagination via above code works in taxonomy category pages. 
But when am calling this function in page `<?php paginate_posts(); ?>` it isn't working. But can't understand what is the issue ?

Comment: try this link, My answer is that [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996690/how-to-create-pagination-in-page-code-in-wordpress/34013174#34013174)

Comment: see I have copied above code and put it directly in page. And also added new query with my options($wp_query = new WP_Query();$wp_query>query('post_type=product&paged='.get_query_var('paged').'&odrerby=ID&posts_per_page=15&order=DESC');) Seems now it is working. Just numbering is wrong. For example if I have 2pages and I clicked to go to second page it shows 01/02 instead of 02/02. Do you have any thoughts? @bhaveshvala

Comment: It is working now I just missed $args inside of query function, like this $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); @bhaveshvala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making my pagination code work inside page I put code inside of page where I want to display pagination and then I added new query with my arguments and it works now. And my final code looks like this:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $wp_query->query('post_type=product&paged='.get_query_var('paged').'&odrerby=ID&posts_per_page=15&order=DESC');
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
    $current = str_pad($current, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $total = str_pad($wp_query->max_num_pages, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $pagination_args = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => 0,
        'mid_size' => 0,
        'next_text' => _("&raquo;"),
        'prev_text' => _("&laquo;"),
    );
    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
        $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(remove_query_arg('s', get_pagenum_link(1))) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

    if (!empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']))
        $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s' => get_query_var('s'));
    $prev = get_previous_posts_link('');
    $next = get_next_posts_link('');
    $links = "<span class='pagexofy'><span class='prev page-numbers'>$prev</span> <span>PAGE $current/$total</span> <span class='next page-numbers'>$next</span></span>";
    echo $links;
?>
```