# How do add the blog next prev navigation?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use custom post type for my journal post but I want to add navigation for previous and next page. So If I have more than 5 post on my journal page, I will page next link or the number 2,3,4, etc... If there is no more post, it should display previous. Right now, my journal page in on the index.php .

And in my wordpress reading settings, I use a static page for my front page displays. My front page is front-page.php and my posts page is journal page. Blog pages show at most 5 posts. Syndication feeds show the most recent 5posts.

How do I add next and previous navigation using my custom post type "journals"?

```
<?php 

    get_header();

    ?> 

    <!-- journal -->
    <section class="container-wrap">

        <?php

            $args  = array('post_type' => 'journals');
            $query = new WP_Query($args);

            while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();

        ?>

        <article class="post-wrap">

            <header>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-title">
                    <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </a>
                <span class="post-date"><?php echo(types_render_field('date', array('format' => 'm.d.Y') )); ?></span>
            </header>
        </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </section>
    <!-- /journal -->

    <?php 

    get_footer();

    ?>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-you-add-next-previous-buttons-to-pagination

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`paginate_links`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) hook in combination with a custom `WP_Query` array. Make sure to specify the `paged` array parameter for the query. This sets up the query to give back paged results.

```
  <?php
    // 1- Setup paging parameter
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // 2- Setup WP_query variable to get last 12 posts
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'post_type' => 'journals',
      'orderby' => 'most_recent',
      'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // 3- Setup new loop
    if($the_query->have_posts()) : 
      while($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        $the_query->the_post();

    // 4- Output parameters you want here
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<h4><a href="' . the_permalink() . 'title="Read more">' . the_title() . '</a></h4>';
        echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>';
        echo the_excerpt();
        echo '</div>';

    // 5- close up loop
      endwhile;
    endif;

    // 6- Output paginate_links just below post loop
    echo paginate_links( array(
      'base' => str_replace( 999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999 ) ) ),
      'format' => '?paged=%#%',
      'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
      'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    // 7- reset post data query
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
  ?>
```

Comment: I can only see the url. 
http://localhost:8888/test/dev/journals/memories-jar/Memories jar
http://localhost:8888/test/dev/journals/memories-jar/ @lemon kazi

Comment: I try to use something like this, but it doesn't work. Do you know how to make it work for my custom type. https://digwp.com/2013/01/display-blog-posts-on-page-with-navigation/ @lemon kazi

Comment: yes use post-type on $wp_query->query('showposts=5&post_type=journals' . '&paged='.$paged);

Comment: Is that for the code you provided? or from the link I sent? @Lemon Kazi

Comment: for the link u provided in your last comment saw there is a $wp_query

Comment: I change the code. Can you take a look? The navigation show up but it doesn't update posts. Did I miss something. @Lemon Kazi

Answer (score 0):

Try this my code it's working on my site http://www.thehiddenwhy.com/blog/ please this link [How to create pagination in page code in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996690/how-to-create-pagination-in-page-code-in-wordpress/34013174#34013174)